# Text content in main page is displayed in iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe and I want to make a part of the text in the main page to be chopped off/hidden, otherwise it's being displayed in the iframe.

[Click here to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DayOl.png)

How can I make the overflowed part of the text to be hidden?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<iframe src="page2.html" name="iframe1" id="iframe1" height="100%" width="100%" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 4px; height:100%; width:90%;"></iframe>

<h1>MY HEADLINE</h1>
<h3><a href="abc1.html" target="iframe1">Link 1 - abc ...................Z</a></h3>
<h3><a href="abc2.html" target="iframe1">Link 2 - abc ...................Z</a></h3>
<h3><a href="abc3.html" target="iframe1">Link 2 - abc ...................Z</a></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<center>Hello world</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed the body-tag in page2.html into `<body style="background-color:white;">` and it seems to solve my problem.